# Display the name but submit the ID with jQuery tag-it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, multi-select, tag-it

Thanks for your time reading and helping!

I'm using the jQuery "tag-it" plugin: https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it

I've already checked the current questions and answers on the site, but they didn't help to achieve the 100% of what I need. I need help with the last step.

What I'm trying to do is, when the user is writing an email address, the system suggests what users belong to that address.

The suggestions are generated in a PHP page and I take them using AJAX from the plugin. The format given is this:

```
[
 {"value": "13", "label": "Mauricio"},
 {"value": "4", "label": "Manolo"}
]
```

"value" is the ID of the user and "label", the name of the person.

In the example, "Manalo" and "Mauricio" are displayed as suggestions to select. But when they are selected, what is displayed is the ID of the user (the "value"), not the name (the "label").

What I want to do is to display the name of the selected users but when I send the form, only the IDs are sent.

This is the current code. Thanks a lot for the help again.

```
$(".users").tagit({
    autocomplete: {
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'test_json.php?text=' + request.term,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        value: item.value
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    },
});
```

Comment: how to send data ???

Comment: Not sure what do you mean here.

Comment: @Fernan do you got the solution ? if you figured out please share with me

Comment: No, I couldn't make it work. I just changed the plugin to select2, which is not the solution I was looking for but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

Get the selected option value from the jquery Autocomplete

```
$(".users").tagit({
    autocomplete: {
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'test_json.php?text=' + request.term,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {

                response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        value: item.value
                    }
                }));
            },
select: function(event, ui) {
         //For better understanding kindly alert the below commented code

         var selectedObj = ui.item;
         alert(selectedObj.value);
    }

        });
    },
    },
});
```

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't do anything. Like the parameter didn't exist.